# App.js: Cannot find module 'node-releases/data/processed/envs.json'

Tags: react-native, syntax-error

How can I solve this? I installed react navigation and this happened. I followed the instruction in this link - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation. I am confused on how to search to solve this.

```javascript
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import GoBanner from './src/component/molecul/GoBanner'
import GoInfo from './src/component/molecul/GoInfo'
import GoNews from './src/component/molecul/GoNews'
import MainFeatures from './src/container/organism/MainFeature'
import SearchBar from './src/component/molecul/SearchBar'
import ScrollableProduct from './src/container/organism/ScrollableProduct'
import NavBar from './src/container/organism/NavBar'
import GoPay from './src/container/organism/GoPay'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
          {/* Search Bar */}
          <SearchBar />
          {/* Gopay */}
          <GoPay />
          {/* Main Feature */}
          <MainFeatures />
          <View style={{ height: 17, backgroundColor: '#F2F2F4', marginTop: 20 }}></View>
          {/* News Section */}
          <GoNews />
          {/* Internal Information Section */}
          <GoInfo />
          {/* Gofood Banner Section */}
          <GoBanner />
          {/* Nearby Restaurant */}
          <ScrollableProduct />
        </ScrollView >
        <NavBar />
      </View >
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Comment: Please provide complete information in your question or provide some code. What is your project based on? Expo or React Native CLI(bare project).

Comment: my project based on React Native CLI, i had add my code

Comment: Try installing this package 'npm install --save node-releases'

Comment: Hope you can teach me more about react native

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Why is the syntax highlighting seemingly off for JavaScript (not a rhetorical question)? Should it be changed to something else than JavaScript (`lang-js`, `lang-javascript`, `lang-jsx` ([JSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#JSX)), `lang-mjs`, and `lang-cjs` are supposedly equivalent)? Is it just another failing of the syntax highlighter used here on this platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing this package `npm install --save node-releases`